# Submitted .cod files on BlackBerry app world has error (...attempts to acces a secure API)

Tags: blackberry, publishing, blackberry-world

We submit a .zip file on Blackberry app world for publishing. But they return it because they said that there is an error: **Error starting MyApp: Module 'MyApp' attempts to access a secure API**. I searched about this error and it all said that this error will appear if my app is not sign. But we are sure that is is signed because we sign it before building and submitting it to the Testers. What could  be wrong? Another thing we use the .jad to install it on the devices, and if we open the .jad we could see all the signing there. Is it possible that the signing just happens on the .jad and not on the .cod files?

Comment: are your testers testing on real devices?  not simulators?

Comment: Yes of course, that's why we were confused when Blackberry app world didn't approved the publishing of our app because of the error reported.

Comment: If you have used OTA to install on testers, then you probably unzipped the cod file, so it possible that the cods you submitted to BB World are not the same.  You can copy the unzipped cods directly from your OTA web site and then be sure that they are the same.  Trouble is that means more 'adds' when installing on BB World!

Comment: i found the answer and solved it, read it if you're interested. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that having large sizes of `.cod` or the last `.cod` having 64kb and up in size causes the problem. I found some posts on *Blackberry developers forum* saying that when you have `.cod` like this, when you install the app via OTA and you use mobile network, some network truncates the `.cod` thus removing the signature. The solution for this problem is to add an image(approximately **10kb**) on `res` and rebuild the application so that the an extra `cod` could be created and the sizes of other `cods` would be lessen. My `cods` that I submitted having this problem has **86kb** and the last `cod` is **63kb**, I added a **10kb** image and rebuild the application. New `cod` was added and the sizes of other `cods` lessen. The size of my maximum `cod` is just **74kb**, and the newly created `cod` is **25kb**. This is the set of `cods` which was published successfully on *app world*.

**References:**

[First link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-World-Development/Secure-api-64k-cod-file-still-an-issue/m-p/1857359/highlight/true#M13337)

[Second link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-World-Development/Unable-to-install-app-from-the-app-world/td-p/1459003)

[Third link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Error-Starting-a-Signed-Application/td-p/188900)